# Return a value from Activity to Service

Tags: android

How can I launch the activity from the service and get the value from it? `startActivityForResult()` does not apply to services, and besides the function is Deprecated.

My task includes the following limitations:

1. The service is called from the outside, so it's necessary to use it.
2. The data must be received in the service execution flow. Therefore it's not suitable to launch the activity from the service, and then launch the service from it. In the activity, you need to fill in some values and return control back to the service with received data, in the same place as the service entry point is.
3. The target version of android is 6.0 (API 23). Maybe it limits some possibilities too.

For now I got by synchronized singletone with a map inside, but it's just a crutch...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps the best solution here is to see a working example. Inside location samples, https://github.com/android/location-samples, there is a `ForegroundLocation` sample. This sample has a `ForegroundLocationService` in it which binds to the activity if the activity is on the screen and promotes itself to the foreground if the activity is not on the screen. It also has means of retrieving the data generated by the service for use in the UI.

It might not be 100% what you are looking for but it will give you some working sample code.